# Autofilter a range of time in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have tried to create a macro to auto filter the time range from 12:00:00 am to 3:00:00 am. But the code gave me an error. What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub TIME()


 T1 = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
 T2 = TimeSerial(0, 3, 0)

 ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$L$597064").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & T1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criterial2:="<" & T2


End Sub
```

Comment: There shouldn't be an "L" in the word "Criteria" - so change `Criterial2` to `Criteria2`

Comment: I have deleted the "L" but my code still doesn't work. It runs without error but it cannot filter the range of time as expected. Nothing is filtered.

Comment: Try changing the 3 minutes to be 3 hours and see if that helps.

Comment: i.e. change `T2 = TimeSerial(0, 3, 0)` to `T2 = TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)`

Comment: thanks, it is solved